# failed to save new file with time stamp

Tags: java, android, eclipse, save, timestamp

i want to save file into sd card and i use timestamp so if already have a file with the same name are not replaced
this is my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
            boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {

                mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
                mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            } else {

                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            }

            try {

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'/'HHmm");
                String timestamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                String filename = "_" + timestamp + ".txt";

                File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Preposisi Removal/PreposisiRemoval");
                myFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream FOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile+filename);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                        new OutputStreamWriter(FOut);
                        myOutWriter.append(tv.getText());
                        myOutWriter.close();
                        FOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Save Files Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button.setOnClickListener (this);

}
```

but when i run it, i get toast message "/mnd/sdcard/Preposisi Removal/PreposisiRemoval_20140117/0633.txt: open failed:ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I guess because there is no folder "Preposisi Removal"
so how to automatic create the folder if it does not exist?

or is there anything wrong with my coding? 
each pressing the save button i want to save the new file instead of overwriting the previous file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the directory first (this won't throw an error if it already exists):

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Preposisi Removal/");
directory.mkdirs();
```

Then create the file in that directory (use the name complete with timestamp and suffix):

```
File myFile = new File(directory, "PreposisiRemoval" + filename); //Changed code
//myFile.getParentFile().mkdir();  //No longer required
myFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream FOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);  //Changed code
```

EDIT:

Ok, now I see the actual problem which is this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'/'HHmm");
```

The timestamp part of your filename has a '/' in it. You cannot use that character in a filename because it indicates a folder or directory. Change it to another character, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'_'HHmm");
```

Your code (or the updates I suggested previously) should then work.

Comment: error sir, get message "open failed: ENOENT(No such file or directory)

Comment: Is the SDcard available and do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest? I see you check the external storage status in the preceding code but then go for the file save regardless of the outcome.

Comment: im have permission in android manifest like this <uses-permission 
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />" and sd card available, if there is something wrong with the code checking my sd card? 
I just followed some tutorials here. I am a beginner in android programming, please give instructions if there are errors, I just want to make the process of file storage

Comment: I've just noticed the actual problem with is a / within your filename. Please see my edit above.